# CDI works in JAX-RS MessageBodyWriter but not in MessageBodyReader

Tags: jax-rs, cdi, jboss-weld

I am using CDI to inject things into my JAX-RS MessageBodyWriters and MessageBodyReaders. This works well for the MessageBodyWriters but not for the MessageBodyReaders. Also, Interceptors work on the writers, but not on the readers.

Can anyone explain whether this is desired behavior or what I might be doing wrong?

I am using JBOSS 6, so Weld is my CDI implementation.

Jan

Answer (score 0):

Ha! Never mind - I totally forgot that I was instantiating the reader directly in my testing code. When I obtain e reference via CDI, the injection works fine -> http://facepalm.org